# Is there a way to requeue bounced mails in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

We have a postfix server which delivery via a smarthost / relay.
Due to a misconfiguration we 60 emails were bounced back.

```
Nov 25 07:48:06 example postfix/smtp[2632]: F3F1F1A82421: to=<example@gmail.com.invalid>, relay=mail.example.com[....]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0/0.09/0.03, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.example.com[....] said: 550 Relay not
```

Is there a way to requeue these mails or are they "lost" and have to be regenerated by the mail sender?

Comment: For the record: A 4XX SMTP response means "Not now, try again later" and the MTA will defer the message and try to resend it at a later time; a **5xx** response means "No, and don't ask me again" and the MTA will accept that and cause a bounce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. While the error is temporary, postfix will retry to send the mail in regular intervals.

But with a final error like this the process is finished. The mail will have to be sent again.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting that somehow. Is there a option to "log" outgoing mails to be able to retry final errors as well? This would be kind of cool.

Comment: No, that won't be cool. Final errors are *by the definition* the ones which say "don't retry". You may enable [soft_bounce](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#soft_bounce) temporarily, but don't run a system like this for too long, or others may ban you (your server will get listed as bad behaving host in various black lists). Read manual carefully and make sure you understand the meaning of each single word, because consequences could be be surprising.

Comment: Well, the bounced mail is returned to the sender. If the sending address has a mailbox you'll find the mails there. Depending on the MTA configuration the original mail can be there as well as an attachment.